# Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled... - Under IIS 10 Selenium testing only

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, selenium-chromedriver

I'm struggling with a really odd issue that only occurs in a certain scenario.

We are upgrading our web hosting environment from win 2012 IIS 8 to win 2019 IIS 10.  We have web apps built in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and running under CLR version 4.0 Integrated.

I have a lot of automated testing that runs using Selenium (Selenium.WebDriver nuget package 3.141).  One of our pages has the ability to swap out the master page it uses based on the form it is displaying.  The testing works great in our existing environments.  And other forms still work fine as well.

However, in the new IIS 10 environment, with one specific master page, and only for this particular form page, if:

- Selenium posts the page (via a submit button)
- it returns with a validation error
- Selenium then posts it a second time via the same button with either valid or invalid data
- the page blows up with the following error:

> ERROR LEVEL 1
>
> HttpUnhandledException -> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.  StackTrace:    at
> System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)    at
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    at
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at
> ASP.plt_pltgeneral_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
> Files\root\82a5c1fe\a330c9cd\App_Web_w4e2wdui.14.cs:line 0    at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
> Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> ERROR LEVEL 2
>
> ArgumentException -> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page
> EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes,
> this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
> originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If
> the data is valid and expected, use the
> ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
> register the postback or callback data for validation.  StackTrace:
> at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId,
> String argument)    at System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String
> uniqueID, String eventArgument)    at
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.LoadPostData(String
> postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)    at
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData,
> Boolean fBeforeLoad)    at
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

This same form works just fine if it is submitted in the same sequence via manual testing.  However if you start the browser via selenium, then pause the test and finish the sequence manually it still blows up.  So there is something with the combination of Selenium, IIS 10, A page being posted back for the second time, and this particular master page.

My current theory since this all works in the existing environment is that there must be something that changed in IIS 10 with the way event validation happens.  It is the same code running in both environments.

I am looking for theories/fixes for why the IIS upgrade would trigger this very specific issue, and what might be triggering it so I can work around it.

EDIT:

I have tracked the issue down to an old hidden drop down list:

```
            <div style="float: right; position: relative; visibility: hidden;" class="nav2">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Visible="false" EnableViewState="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
            </div>
```

Which renders as this HTML:

```
            <div style="float: right; position: relative; visibility: hidden;" class="nav2">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <select name="ctl00$ddlCountry" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ddlCountry\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl00_ddlCountry">
<option value="All">All</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">United States</option>
```

If I modify the wrapping div to make it not render:

```
<div style="float: right; position: relative; visibility: hidden;" class="nav2" runat="server" Visible="false">
```

Then the issue goes away.

In this case this will be a good solution for me since that is cleaning out old code anyway.  However, it still feels like something has changed in IIS (maybe got fixed), to cause this to behave differently.

Comment: It's a server side error, and the server doesn't know Selenium from a real person. Have you tried examining the HTTP requests using the browser's dev tools, Fiddler, Wireshark or some other tool to see what's different about Selenium vs manually doing it?

Comment: I haven't, that would have been an interesting exercise though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being a hidden DropDownList control that .net was rendering even though it was set to invisible.  Once I removed that old code the issue was resolved.

My best guess is that there are two bugs in play here.  A .net bug that renders a control that is supposed to be invisible.  And a new IIS 10/CLR bug that is not ignoring changes to an invisible control.

Those two potential bugs coupled with the invisible control possibly being modified by selenium may have all merged together to create this scenario for me.